# Getting the exit code of a finished process whose pid is known

Tags: shell, unix, exit-code

There is a [vmware api](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProcessInfo.html) which can return the pid and exit code of executed processes. Some how I am getting only the pid but not the exit code(may be due to unsupported guest os).

Generally it returns the out put like this :

```
   name = 'chmod',
   pid = 2377,
   owner = 'reuben',
   cmdLine = '"/bin/chmod" +x /home/reuben/some_script.sh',
   startTime = 2014-10-14T07:31:07Z,
   endTime = <unset>,
   exitCode = <unset>
```

As you can see I am not getting the exit code. But it works with other supported guest OS.

**Note**: though it is not returning the exit code but the process is finishing successfully.

So is there any unix command to know the exit code from the pid ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux, where are the return codes stored of system daemons and other processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441760/linux-where-are-the-return-codes-stored-of-system-daemons-and-other-processes)

Comment: @TomZych It looks WMWare specific, so I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Comment: That would not make sense. After process termination the PID may be reused, that is, it would be a non-deterministic query. So it must involve some logging facility, which at least records the pid, the termination time and the exit code of the process, to achieve such a functionality. I have an idea how to create one, but it's far beyond the bounds of this question.