# How to get the full returned value of a child process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fork, waitpid

I need to catch the returned value of a child process..

The problem is: with using the [waitpid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) function I can catch only 8 bits of the returned value

> WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
>                 returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the
>                 least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
>                 specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
>                 for a return statement in main().  This macro should be
>                 employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.

How can I catch the full int value that is returned from `main()` ?

EDIT: Stackoverflow forced me to edit the question as it linked another answered question but it has nothing to do with mine!

Answer (score 7):

[POSIX requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) that the full exit value be passed in the `si_status` member of the `siginfo_t` structure passed to the SIGCHLD handler, if it is appropriately established via a call to `sigaction` with  `SA_SIGINFO` specified in the flags:

> If si_code is equal to CLD_EXITED, then si_status holds the exit value of the process; otherwise, it is equal to the signal that caused the process to change state. **The exit value in si_status shall be equal to the full exit value** (that is, the value passed to _exit(), _Exit(), or exit(), or returned from main()); **it shall not be limited to the least significant eight bits of the value**.

(Emphasis mine).

**Note that upon testing, it appears that Linux does not honour this requirement and returns only the lower 8 bits of the exit code in the si_status member**. Other operating systems may correctly return the full status; FreeBSD does. [See test program here](https://gist.github.com/davmac314/e4243431ed57eb1ae6dfbf885d72f5ba).

Be wary, though, that is not completely clear that you will receive an individual SIGCHLD signal for every child process termination (multiple pending instances of a signal can be merged), so this technique is not completely infallible. It is probably better to find another way to communicate a value between processes if you need more than 8 bits.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you pretty much can't.  Traditionally, the exit status of a process under Unix/Linux is propagated as an 8-bit value.  You can return any integer from `main` that you like, you can call `exit` with any integer that you like, but only the low-order 8 bits are available to the parent via any of the `wait` functions.

The reason `WEXITSTATUS`is documented as returning only the low-order 8 bits of the status is that those are the only bits that there are.

If you're trying to pass arbitrary data from a subprocess back to its parent, the exit status is not the way to do it.  Me, I normally print data to the standard output, and have the caller capture it using `popen` or the equivalent.

---

Addendum: I thought the kernel didn't even record the full `int`-sized exit status, and that it was therefore impossible to retrieve it by any means, but as davmac explains in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982730/how-to-get-the-full-returned-value-of-a-child-process/50989535#50989535), you might be able to get your hands on it in a `SIGCHLD` handler.

Comment: "The short answer is that you can't" - not completely true, see my answer below.

Comment: @davmac Oh!  Thanks.  I didn't know that.  (I've always shied strongly away from `SIGCHLD`, because my personal belief is that it's impossible for mere mortals to implement `SIGCHLD` handlers without drowning in neverending race conditions, but the `si_status` thing is good to know.)

Comment: "I've always shied strongly away from SIGCHLD" - to be honest that is probably wise. You're right that signal handling is tricky to get right in general.

Comment: Well, this is interesting - I wrote a test program to check, and it turns out that Linux doesn't honour this particular POSIX requirement. :( See my updated answer. This makes your answer completely correct after all.

Comment: @davmac I don't have a problem with signal handling in general, but yes, `SIGCHLD` is a viper's nest.  What a mess.  (And this discrepancy wrt Linux and the lower 8 bits only makes it worse.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only ways you can get it is by `strace`ing the process and looking for the exit system call**s**, which now seem to be `exit_group`, by debugging, or possibly by using some ugly hacks like `LD_PRELOAD`. I.e. nothing unintrusive.

For zombie processes the exit code can be found in the [last column of `/proc/<pid>/stat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18442112/918959) but it is already `& 0xFF`.